# How to know the details of parameters of any RFC function

Tags: sap-basis, sapjco3

I am looking to retrieve following Session time and password profile parameters for SAP via SAP JCo, via the RFC-enabled function module `TH_GET_PARAMETER`. How to know the details of the parameters of this function module, or any other RFC-enabled function module generally speaking (without access to the SAP backend system).

Examples of profile parameters:

1. `rdisp/gui_auto_logout`
2. `login/min_password_lng`
3. etc.

Comment: For information, these parameters are named the [Profile Parameters](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=Profile%20Parameter&product=ABAP_PLATFORM).

Comment: @SandraRossi i checked that "TH_GET_PARAMETER" function module is used to get it, but i ain't sure how to get in SAP JCo

Comment: You may actualize your question and people would be happy to answer it. Possibly, it could be "how to know the details of parameters of any RFC function?" (it doesn't exist in Stack Overflow yet/metadata questions are only about the cache)

Comment: Done, Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code works well:

It connects to RFC "TH_GET_PARAMETER", which has one input and one output. You need to input the respective parameter and print the output.

```
import com.sap.conn.jco.*;

public class GetPasswordParameters {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("SAP-ECC");
            JCoFunction function = destination.getRepository().getFunction("TH_GET_PARAMETER");

            if (function == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Function TH_GET_PARAMETER not found in SAP system.");
            }

            // Set parameters to be retrieved
            String[] parameterNames = {
                    "rdisp/gui_auto_logout",
                    "login/min_password_lng",
                    "login/min_password_digits",
                    "login/min_password_letters",
                    "login/min_password_lowercase",
                    "login/min_password_uppercase",
                    "login/min_password_specials",
                    "login/password_expiration_time",
                    "login/password_change_for_SSO",
                    "login/password_history_size",
                    "login/multi_login_users",
                    "login/fails_to_session_end",
                    "login/update_logon_timestamp"
            };

            // Populate the parameter table
            for (String parameterName : parameterNames) {             
        function.getImportParameterList().setValue("PARAMETER_NAME",parameterName);
function.execute(destination);
String value = function.getExportParameterList().getString("PARAMETER_VALUE");
System.out.println(value);
        }
} catch (JCoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```